# How are todo apps structured on backend?

Tags: architecture, backend

I am wondering how to design architecture of app where user can sign up for the app and than sign in. How it should be structured on backend? Good example is TODO app. Do every user has his own DB which is created on sign up, or there is single DB and every record has column which tells which user this todo belongs?

Maybe it is foolish question but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: Most of the time the second option is taken since it is more cost efficient, easier to maintain and all in all much simpler.

Comment: Seperated databases are used when a single database scalability limits have been reached. In this case the data is scattered across multiple database instances and they are separated not on the user level more than on a higher some organization level (like account). This technique is called sharding.

Answer (score 0):

If I see the question, a TODO app is specific to each user. There is no sharing of data between users. They may want to collaborate on single TODO which I would implement as duplication rather than relation. It is also very fluid in the sense that I would like users to be able create their todos their way. This makes my first choice a document based NoSQL database where there will be one document per user. It would still be one database which can of course be scaled by adding clusters or something else of your choice.